# Bf-cache and form elements

Tags: react-final-form

I am using Material-ui and React-final-form. Some form elements get prefilled from the browser cache, such as a login form. The problem is that this does not trigger an onChange event in React-final-form, which leaves the form field state in the "empty" state, which is visually problematic. As soon as a render cycle is triggered, React-final-form picks up the change and the ui is good. I'm wondering how to trigger this programmatically.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wow. Good question! If you had a ref to the input itself, perhaps you could check it’s DOM value onMount and call the onChange function manually if props.input.value was !==. Just hypothesizing here....?